# Migration from 32 bit to 64 bit -> Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, winforms, xls, xlsx

We have 32 bit windows application developed with vs2005.In this application their is facility were user can upload his details with xls file.
As demand we need to support to 64 bit machine,which we have done.
The only problem we faced is that when user try to upload file system throws an error "'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"
Can u guide me for the same

Comment: Nice job googling that error message.  Twenty one thousand hits are not enough???

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft's Jet driver does not exist in 64-bit form. You have two options:

1. Compile your application to 32-bit only. This will run on 32-bit workstations and WOW64 on 64-bit machines, so you still get the benefit of "supporting" 64-bit machines even though it is running 32-bit.
2. Move to the ACE driver, which comes in 32-bit and 64-bit variants.

Option #1 is probably what I would recommend. This requires the least changes to your application, and your application will likely have very little benefit by running native 64-bit. Secondly, if you do move to ACE for the purpose of supporting 32-bit and 64-bit, now you need to worry about two different ACE drivers, the 64-bit one and the 32-bit one.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem - see [How to enable reading C# Excel files on IIS (reading them locally on the machine where IIS is running works fine)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022224/how-to-enable-reading-c-sharp-excel-files-on-iis-reading-them-locally-on-the-ma)

Rewriting everything using [EP Plus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) for XLSX and [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/) for XLS turned out to be much easier than using Microsoft stuff. Both are freeware and work well.